# Duration Code and Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Both of the following code blocks work on Chrome and Firefox but not on Internet  Explorer 11

I've searched forums and all but I haven't found any solution yet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var starttime = (new Date()).getTime();
  $(window).unload(function(){
    $.post('timetest.php', {spent: (new Date()).getTime() - starttime});
  });
});
</script>  




<script>
function start()
{
        starttime = (new Date()).getTime();
     alert(starttime); 
}
function leave()
{
        stoptime = (new Date()).getTime();        
        var params = "spent="+(stoptime-starttime);
        xmlobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlobj.open('POST', 'timetest.php', true);
        xmlobj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlobj.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlobj.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlobj.send(params);

} 

</script>
<body onload=start() onunload=leave()>
```

Comment: jQuery v1.3? Have you tried with a version [made this decade](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/01/14/jquery-1-3-released/)?

Comment: Yes I have tried latest version, which failed.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `<script>` tags inside the `<head>` or the `<body>`? At the moment it seems as though they are outside of both, which may be causing your issue.

Comment: Yes, Tried both options again. Same result